# Accidentally deleted ~/.gnupg directory, Now couldn't get passwords with pass. Is it recoverable?

Tags: data-recovery, gpg, password-store

As title said, I accidentally deleted  `~/.gnupg` directory.

```
$ pass odysee
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I just want to access my password stored with `pass`.

- Is it recoverable from this state?, Or is this lost cause?

Answer (score 2):

Your key was stored in `~/.gnupg`, and without that `pass` can’t decrypt its passwords. Unless you have a backup of your key or can recover it in some other way, your passwords are not recoverable.

If you want to try undeleting the key files, look for `pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg` (for GnuPG before version 2.1), or for `pubring.kpx` and files named after private key fingerprints with a `.key` extension (for GnuPG 2.1 and later).

Comment: I'm trying to recover the deleted files with `ext4magic`. I've deleted the folder within 1-2days, not sure It'll work. Do you know what name does *key* file usually has?

Comment: The keys are normally stored in `pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg`.

Comment: Newer versions (2.1 and newer) of `gpg` have the private keys as `*.key` files in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/` and the public keys in `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`.